# modify class for specific child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this abstract class which contains a class called Hierarchy holding some variables (unity3d will not display Structs on the inspector window).

This abstract class has some children and while for most of them this Hierarchy class is suitable, for one of them it is not. So I was wondering if it is possible to have a specific Hierarchy class for this child while the remaining children still use the parent Hierarchy class?

```
    public class Hierarchy
{   
public Points points;
}

public class Points
{   
public GameObject[] pointsToActivateOnCorrectAnswer;
public GameObject[] pointsToDeactivateOnCorrectAnswer;

public GameObject[] pointsToActivateOnWrongAnswer;
public GameObject[] pointsToDeactivateOnWrongAnswer;
}
public Hierarchy hierarchy;
```

More specifically, I wish to modify the content of the Points class for one child and not the others, is it possible?

Comment: For example, in this point class I have various arrays containing Points to be activated/deactivated based on a correct/wrong answer. In another situation there might not be a question, rather just a text and a button so the Points class does not fit that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a generic class. Something like this...

```
public class Points
{
    ...
}

public class TextAndButton
{
    ...
}

public class Hierarchy<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
    Hierarchy<T> Hierarchy { get; set; }
}
```

So you can use an instance of `Hierarchy<Point>` just as easily as you can an instance of `Hierarchy<TextAndButton>`.

Answer (score 0):

I might be off topic, but this looks like the perfect use case for an Interface. All classes (like your Point class) could implement a common interface, let's call it IChild that references the common methods and variables Hierarchy needs to update or access. Your Hierarchy class then expects IChild members rather then a specific class, like Point.

When ever you only need to access common methods, you can reference as IChild and when you need a specific class, like Point, you just access it as such.